# "python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 " is displaying

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

In Selenium Webdriver , I am working on Python in Pycharm In which I am using simple class in which two methods are called to open URL in Chrome and Safari respectively.

```
from selenium import webdriver


    class Automation():
        def Safari(self):
            driver = webdriver.Safari()
            driver.get('https://bizplace.theentertainerme.com')

        def Chrome(self):
            driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
            driver.get('https://bizplace.theentertainerme.com')

    auto = Automation
    auto.Safari(self)
```

Now After Executing it, I am getting an error like this:

```
    auto.Safari(self)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I am trying to install self package via command line, its throwing me an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/hh/bwg2n8w54cd7852cx91v21qm0000gp/T/pip-build-XVmlLB/public/setup.py", line 28, in <module>
        setup_cfg_data = read_configuration(path)
      File "/private/var/folders/hh/bwg2n8w54cd7852cx91v21qm0000gp/T/pip-build-XVmlLB/public/setup.py", line 23, in read_configuration
        val = open(val).read()
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './README.rst'
```

Can some one help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to install [the self package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/self/0.0.14), you are not using it in your code, and you do not need it.

Your issue is a simple mistake here when calling your method:

```
auto = Automation
auto.Safari(self)
```

This code is outside your class, the name `self` is not defined here, and you get the error you are seeing:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

The correct way to call your method would be this:

```
auto = Automation
auto.Safari()
```

Since you are calling a method of an instance, `self` (the instance that the actual method you called belongs to) will [automatically be passed as first argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self).

*Do not take this the wrong way, but I think you need to [work your way through the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), as this is somewhat of a basic mistake, and with more complicated code you will run into countless issues like this one and will not enjoy working on your project.*